# A basic question about commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

$A$ is a noetherian ring. $B$ is an flat $A$-algebra. $M$,$N$ are $A$-modules and $M$ is finite generated as an $A$-module. Prove that
$Hom_A (M,N)\otimes B \cong Hom_B (M\otimes B,N\otimes B)$.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I have to ask, what is your definition of flat, because that statement is dangerously close to the definition I know of flatness.

Comment: If $M$ is flat, $Tor_n (M,N)=0$ for all $n>0$ and all $A$-modules $N$.

Comment: @Mizore Please review [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335), especially the suggestions related to **context** and to **choosing a good title**, and then edit accordingly.  "A question about [subject area]" is never a good title for a post.

Comment: Sorry. It’s my first time to use StackExchange to ask question. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tensor-hom adjunction the right hand side is just $\mathrm{Hom}_A(M,N\otimes B)$. Since $A$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated, it is finitely presented, so write it as the cokernel of some map $\phi\colon A^m\to A^n$. Now, taking homs over $A$, we have
$$ \mathrm{Hom}(A^n,N\otimes B)\cong(N\otimes B)^n\cong
\mathrm{Hom}(A^n,N)\otimes B, $$
and similarly for $A^m$, so we get a commutative square arising from $\phi$. The kernels are now isomorphic, so using that $B$ is flat we get
$$ \mathrm{Hom}(M,N\otimes B)\cong\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)\otimes B. $$

Comment: Please refrain from solving questions which are only problem statements.  The popular impression is that doing so is likely to encourage users to treat the site as a homework answering service.